# How to specify sql parameter for loadcache

Tags: ignite

I am using following sql that will load data into cache

```
//There are 2 placeholders in the sql
String sql = "select * from person where id > ? and id < ?"

IgniteCache.loadCache(null, Integer.class.getName(), sql);
```

How could I set the parameters for the sql like the `PreparedStatement` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Ignite doesn't support such formatting on loadCache(). You can just pass multiple  queries:

`IgniteCache.loadCache(null, 
    Integer.class.getName(), sql1,
    Integer.class.getName(), sql2,
    ...);`

Comment: Thanks @Mitya. It is just inconvenient if the query condition is of `Date` type, I have to convert  Date to string, and then user `to_date` in the sql.

Comment: @Tom, I think this is a good feature to implement in Ignite. Also I think it is much better to provide PreparedStatement  directly to IgniteCache.loadCache() this will be very useful if actual load based on user input. Using PreparedStatement statement will protect against SQL injections. Could you create issue in Apache Ignite JIRA?

Comment: Thanks @kuaw26 and Valentin

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you try the following:

```java
String sql = "select * from person where id > %s and id < %s";
String sqlWithParams = String.format(sql, param1, param2);
igniteCache.loadCache(null, sqlWithParams);
```

Comment: Which do you mean: "What to do next" "What not to do next" "Why not do this next"?

Comment: Thanks, this is also a workable solution.

Comment: @LoverofStructure Hi, I meant "Why do not you try the following?"

Comment: @Andrei Okay, then please edit, otherwise people won't know what you mean.